# Increase & Decrease DynamoDb RCU from AWS DataPipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-data-pipeline

I have an [AWS DynamoDb](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) table which is write intensive. I've configured it in the provisioned capacity mode with `10,000` WCU and `1000` RCU.

I'm using [AWS Datapipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/data-pipeline/index.html) to export DynamoDb contents to S3. The pipeline is configured with the read throughput ratio `75%`.

It takes around `~2 hours` to export `~150GB` of data in this setting. When I increased the RCU to `10,000` the export completed in less than 20 minutes.

Is there any way in DataPipeline to increase the provisioined RCU only when my pipeline is running? As this pipeline is configured to run only once in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t control the DynamoDB capacity from within the data pipeline job.

However, you can use AWS Step Functions to [orchestrate ETL jobs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/orchestrate-multiple-etl-jobs-using-aws-step-functions-and-aws-lambda/) with other arbitrary steps. So, your solution could be a scheduled [CloudWatch event that starts a Step Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-target.html) to:

1. Set the capacity of your DynamoDB table. (I think you would need to write a simple Lambda function for this because Step Functions can’t do it directly.)
2. Invoke a Lambda that starts the Data Pipeline job
3. Wait for the job to complete
4. Reset the read capacity of the table

**Additional Resources**

- A [GitHub repository](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-etl-orchestrator) with a sample ETL orchestration workflow.
- [Another example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-high-throughput-genomics-batch-workflows-on-aws-workflow-layer-part-4-of-4/) of orchestrating ETL jobs on AWS Step Functions. The example includes a loop that periodically checks on the status of the job.
- DynamoDB’s [UpdateTable API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html)